# Transform DataFrame: place values in right columns as new rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analyzing a consumer survey and there are both Dutch (NL) and French (FR) respondents. Depending on the answer they gave when we asked about their mother language they got the same questionnaire but translated in Dutch or French. The problem is that the output of Qualtrics (the survey software) gave us the following output:

| User_Language | Q1_NL | Q2_NL | ... | Q1_FR | Q_FR | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NL | 1 | 3 | ... |  |  | ... |
| NL | 4 | 4 | .. |  |  | ... |
| NL | 1 | 3 | ... |  |  | ... |
| NL | 2 | 5 | ... |  |  | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| FR |  |  | ... | 3 | 2 | ... |
| FR |  |  | .. | 4 | 3 | ... |
| FR |  |  | ... | 2 | 5 | ... |
| FR |  |  | ... | 1 | 2 | ... |

As you can see the answers for the Dutch-speaking participants were recorded in the first n columns, while the French answers were recorded in the following n columns.

How can I cut the French answers from the last n columns and append them on the bottom of the DataFrame as those are answers to the exact same questions?

Thanks!

*EDIT: Solutions that make use of grouping by the strings "Q1" or "Q2" are unfortunately not viable as the column names are actually the questions, this was just an example value. I do know the exact range of the French answers and the Dutch answers.*

Comment: can you add some code to show an example dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there aren't any overlapping values you could simply split the data frame into two data frames based on where the dutch values "stop" and the french "start" rename the value columns of those two data frames   Q2_NL and so on to simply Q2 ... and then concatenate those frames again into one.

Comment: Hi! The problem is that there is some demographic about the respondent in the first columns (like User_Language) so simply splitting them is not really an option as you would miss the demographic data in the first columns for the second DataFrame.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this. I rearranged the columns a bit which solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can add a helper column, rename the columns to something common, and `stack`/`unstack`

```
(df
 .assign(index=df.groupby('User_Language').cumcount())
 .set_index(['User_Language', 'index'])
 .rename(columns=lambda c: c.split('_')[0])
 .stack().unstack()
 .droplevel('index').reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  User_Language  Q1  Q2
0           FR   3   2 
1           FR   4   3 
2           FR   2   5 
3           FR   1   2 
4           NL   1   3 
5           NL   4   4 
6           NL   1   3 
7           NL   2   5
```

Comment: Solutions that make use of grouping by the strings "Q1" or "Q2" are unfortunately not viable as the column names are actually the questions, this was just an example value. I do know the exact range of the French answers and the Dutch answers.

Comment: @SDR3078 can you provide an example of the real format?

Comment: Q1_NL = "Hoeveel hou je van bier?" (How much do you like beer) and its counterpart in French Q1_FR = "Vous aimez beaucoup la bière ?". The column name is really the question itself in both French and Dutch.

Comment: @SDR3078 then it should work, you'll just lose the question "text". What would be the expected output here?

Comment: I would like for the column names to keep the Dutch question string

Comment: I would like to add that the "Q1_NL = " is not included in the column name, this is just to clarify

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to `group` the dataframe along column axis and select the first  non null value per row

```
s = df.set_index('User_Language')
s.groupby(s.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).first()
```

---

```
              Q1 Q2
User_Language      
NL             1  3
NL             4  4
NL             1  3
NL             2  5
FR             3  2
FR             4  3
FR             2  5
FR             1  2
```

Comment: Solutions that make use of grouping by the strings "Q1" or "Q2" are unfortunately not viable as the column names are actually the questions, this was just an example value. I do know the exact range of the French answers and the Dutch answers.

Comment: @SDR3078 We are not relying on the strings Q1 and Q2..., here we are assuming that the questions end with suffix like `_1 or _2`..

Comment: Yes but that's an assumption we cannot make in this case unfortunately. The column name is literally the question, for example "How much do you like beer" and it's translation in Dutch/French.